# How Node.js http.createServer actually works?

Tags: node.js, http

I can not understand [createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) in Node.js
This is the part of the code that makes me feel stupid

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
 let viewUrl = getViewUrl(req.url);
 fs.readFile(viewUrl, (error, data) => {
   if (error) {
    res.writeHead(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
     res.write("<h1>FILE NOT FOUND</h1>");
     Handle errorswith a 404
}
```

This Incoming Message object, how do we know that it has .url method?
From documentation

```
Specifies the IncomingMessage class to be used. Useful for extending the original IncomingMessage. Default: IncomingMessage
```

Where is req.url actually defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback to `http.createServer()` is called when the `request` event occurs on the server.  That event is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) and the first argument to that event is an `http.IncomingMessage` object which is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).  That object has a number of properties and methods including the `.url` property described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url).

Answer (score 1):

I didnt try what is the output of req.url. But it should come current url.

For your reference req is an object, which has url attribute. ie.

```
const req = {
    url : ''
}
```

I will recommend you to use **express js** http://expressjs.com framework instead of node js core. So you can easily achive lot of things with minimal time.

Comment: Ok, but where in Node.js documentation, can we find req object?

Comment: That is a callback function, Instead of req you can use any other word.